# Downloading a pdf from Chrome immediately opens it

Tags: pdf, preview

I want to save some pdfs but whenever I do, it opens automatically in preview and is really annoying. How do I stop it?

Answer (score 2):

When you download a file in Chrome, you have a tab at the bottom of the screen. The right hand side of the tab has a popup where you most likely have "always open with system viewer" checked. Uncheck, and it should no longer automatically open.

Comment: I can verify that on my computer that checkbox works as advertised.